# How to include only specific parts of UI Bootstrap using Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bower

I'm using the accordion, tooltips and transition components of [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

I can [create a custom build with the online tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af6fn.png) on the UI Bootstrap website, which will create a minified and non-minified JS file containing only the components I selected, without overhead.

However, I don't want to use the online tool to compile my custom version of UI Bootstrap, instead I want to compile my own version locally, preferably using the tools I already use; Bower, Grunt and NPM.

So my question: How can I create my own version of UI Bootstrap locally?

---

`bower install angular-ui-bootstrap`, and then calling `Grunt build` in `bower_components/angular-ui-bootstrap` creates a UI Bootstrap build that includes *all* modules, there's probably a way to do the same with only a subset of the modules, but I could not figure this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done by using the following command

```
grunt build:moduleName1:moduleName2:moduleName3....:moduleNameN
```

For example if you require the build to contain only **tabs** and **buttons** module , then the grunt command will be like

```
grunt build:tabs:buttons
```

The generated files will be present in `dist` folder

For the list of module names , check all folder names in `src` folder

The documentation for this is sparse , but if you check the [Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/4c6e0b3b2eeb443b9370ca12ae2ef90d445036c4/Gruntfile.js#L316) , where they register the **build** task , they mention about how to build modules selectively

Answer (score 0):

It is not as easy as I expected (and as it should be).

Take a look at the [Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) of the project. You will see that they do quite a lot. Converting HTML and CSS to JS, concating all the scripts in such way they are loadable by others. Moreover the file is quite difficult for orientation; it even includes custom tasks.

To mimic its behaviour I suggest this: Download it via Bower as you normally do. Copy its node dependecies to your `package.json` dependencies. Then copy the `Gruntfile.js`, change he routes, and try deleting some parts of the code until you reach a point when you cannot remove more lines without breaking it. It is not a nice way, it should be however successful.

If one had a lot of time, the build script is a good candidate for a deep refactoring. Moving custom tasks to standalone files (or projects), documenting the flow, and maybe implementing standard tasks for some steps (e.g. CSS minification).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I noticed the huge and messy Gruntfile before posting my question, but couldn't find any obvious way to use it for creating my own build. I'm looking for a more detailed guide on how to do so. I'll add a bounty to my question for motivation.

Comment: I added a bounty if you're interested.